# how to remove trailing slash with page number from url using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have URLs like this http://domain.com/questions/ask/2

1. I want to find the trailing slash with page number from URLs and then remove the trailing slash with page number using jquery or javascript.
2. I want the URLs like this http://domain.com/questions/ask

Please help me to solve. Thanks in advance

UPDATE
 The URLs are /1, /2 and so on... the page number is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

If you're url is constant, you can just use substring to remove the page number like so:

`"http://domain.com/questions/ask/2".substring(0, 31)`

Of course, you have to edit the end number for the domain you have.

If you want to remove whatever comes after the last `/`, it's even easier:

```
var myUrl = "http://domain.com/questions/ask/2";
myUrl.substring(0, myUrl.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce a non-trailing-slash policy, then you don't have to deal with them.

Create an `.htaccess` file in the `documentroot`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```